# Is it necessary to log http 404 exceptions

Tags: asp.net, exception, error-handling

I have below code in global application error event. If there is any invalid url, this event gets fired. Is it required to log http 404 errors.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

Exception lastException = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
//log exception

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is quite general, but logging 404 pages is quite good for several reasons.

By logging 404 pages you can `find broken links` on your web site and also to see how frequent it happens, that way you can create `redirects` if needed.

But it's your choice of course if you want to that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers are configured to write 404s along with all other requests and responses to its access log.

Answer (score 0):

It's on your own if you want to log this error. Errors can also be handled automaticly using web.config inside system.web section, like this:

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
```

Basicly server will automaticly redirect to declared pages on specific error number.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is quite simply: "No, it's not required to log 404 errors."

It is best practice to have a process in place for handling 404 errors to maximize the search engine optimization of your site, though.